# installing pandas-profiling error in python 3.10

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

I am trying to install pandas-profiling in python 3.10 using pychan installation package option. It is giving error. I tried the same using command prompt. Giviing the same error.
Few last lines of error are as below:

'-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j19ut5x7\phik_da8a6ed5567b4ca3b73ac99e2a8c743e\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\phik\lib']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for phik
ERROR: Could not build wheels for phik, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Any suggestion to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously encountered the same challenge and I could resolve it by doing the following two steps in exactly this order:

1. Update setuptools: based on your information provided you are using pip, therefore the command is the following one: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`
2. Now run the installation command (as provided by the official documentation: https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/): `pip install pandas-profiling`

As an alternative, in case you are using Anaconda these two steps will be as follows:

1. Update setuptools: `conda upgrade setuptools`
2. Install pandas-profiling from Anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling`

Hope this helps!